# Acceptable length of url to be stored as unique MySql/PHP

Tags: mysql, database

I want to store url's as unique in a mysql database table but with string type varchar and text the length of a 1000 is too long. Lengths of Search engine friendly url's can be typically long,whats an acceptable length?

Comment: Possibly of use: http://www.supermind.org/blog/740/average-length-of-a-url-part-2

Comment: If you are using VARCHAR, I'm not sure why you think 1000 is too long.  VARCHAR only uses the space it needs for a given entry.

Comment: when i declare the varchar as UNIQUE it needs a length to go with it so i would prefer to call it with no length so it can use the maximum of 65000(i think) if possible just to be covered

Answer (score 1):

There really is no length that will guarantee unique- if you want to make sure a string of a given length is unique, you need to take a hash of the string and compare it, MD5 and SHA1 are common algoritms people use.

Comment: Which is obviously still not an absolute guarantee of uniqueness.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, an MD5 hash of a string is unique for all practical purposes

Comment: Still not guaranteed to be unique, which is a requirement of a URL.